# Is there anyway to remove user from puppet repo if firstly user was removed from repo with present state?

Tags: linux, repository, settings, puppet

I'm not an expert in puppet and I couldn't find an answer for my question. I deleted part of code which describes user from puppet repo (I didn't change his ensure from present to absent - my bad). Happily I went home but on the other day I saw that the users still exists when checked /etc/passwd. I tried to restore the user and change his ensure to absent but it is not helping. Puppet constantly creates that user. Is there anyway to solve that? How to correctly remove the user?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How to remove user from puppet if the user doesn't exist in puppet repo but puppet still creates the user?

Comment: I assure you that Puppet *does not* create a given user on a particular client node unless that node's catalog instructs it that the user should be present.  Likewise, I assure you that Puppet does at least attempt to remove users where the target node's catalog specifies that the user should be absent.  However, we don't have enough information to determine what is actually in the catalog for the node(s) of interest to you, much less *why* those are the contents.  For such debugging questions, we generally expect a [mre] that demonstrates the issue.